# Emacs-like syntax highlighting in Vim

Tags: vim, emacs

I am originally an Emacs user and decided to give Vim a try, but I really don't like Vim's default very dark syntax colouring and really miss the colors of my old Emacs.

The only thing that I found to get Emacs' colours in Vim was that link:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=63

I downloaded the file in my ~/.vim/colors and used the command `:colorscheme emacs` to activate it, but the result was very far from Emacs' colors and really close to Vim's default theme.

And anyways, in the script description they say themselves that they did not go too far in copying Emacs' colors.

Does anybody know something really efficient for doing that, something that goes really far, tweaking everything possible to import Emacs' colours in vim ?

(Or maybe am I doing something wrong with the script that I already downloaded ?)

Edit:

I'm running GNU Emacs 24.4.1, console mode, under Ubuntu 14.04. I mainly edit C and C++ files and never ever modified anything about Emacs' colour scheme.

I am also using that version of Vim (output of vim --version):

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec  9 2014 17:36:39)
Included patches: 1-488
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/usr/include/tcl8.6  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1  
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby2.1-2.1.2/debian/lib -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby-2.1 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Comment: FYI: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I'm looking for: this is for making emacs look more like vim, what I need is something to make Vim look more like Emacs :)

Comment: `vim -u NONE tmp.cpp` opens vim without sourcing .vimrc, `:syntax on` turns on the default vim highlighing `:source emacs.vim` enables the emacs highlight for me

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about what you dislike or how things should work.  Effectively, you are excluding everyone except those who are experts on both Emacs and Vim; and they probably will not think your question is well-defined.  You could improve your question tremendously by explaining what exactly you are looking for.  For one thing, there is no such thing as a singular standard Emacs color palette -- what Emacs looks like depends on the version, the distro, the terminal setup, the mode, the theme, etc.

Comment: And was emacs running on console or an independent gui? Are you using vim or gvim? Have you tried the various available colour schemes? Try `:colorscheme` and press `ctrl-d` to get the available schemes in your installation.